# NuGet API Get Version of package

Tags: api, get, request, nuget

I am trying to get the newest version from a package (in my case im trying it with the StyleCopAnalyzer Package https://www.nuget.org/packages/StyleCop.Analyzers).

My goal is to find out what the newest version of this package is, im trying this with the following get api call:

https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3/StyleCop.Analyzers/index.json

Due to some mistakes in the request, i get this json back:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Error>
<Code>BlobNotFound</Code>
<Message>The specified blob does not exist. RequestId:c2c2ffba-701e-0063-0daa-e47670000000 Time:2019-03-27T14:38:14.3708948Z</Message>
</Error>
```

I created this request with the help of the this doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/api/overview

Thanks in advance for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on @`zivkan`'s answer, I found [this post](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/SemVer2-support-for-nuget.org-(server-side)) useful for background context.

Of particular note is where the NuGet server maintainers announce that they will be adding support for "semver 2.0" packages via this endpoint:

> Today, there are two registration hives visible from the api/v3/index.json:
>
> 1. https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1/
> 2. https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-gz/
>
> We will be adding a third:
>
> 1. https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-semver2-gz/

What wasn't obvious to me through the docs is that the `semver2` endpoint returns metadata for **non-semver 2** packages as well (upon reflection, this makes sense as any package following semver 1.0 conventions is forward-compatible with semver 2.0)

I've updated my code to no longer use
`https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3/` in any context and **always use** `https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2`.

This change simplifies my validation code, includes the [package I was looking for](https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/blazorinputfile/index.json) *(as well as 121 others)*.

`Peter K`'s package can be resolved using:

https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/stylecop.analyzers/index.json

Answer (score 0):

The URL you provided is documented on the [package metadata page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/api/registration-base-url-resource). The part that talks about the URL format has this:

> GET {@id}/{LOWER_ID}/index.json
>
> Name  In  Type    Required    Notes
>
> LOWER_ID  URL string  yes The package ID, lowercased
>
> The LOWER_ID value is the desired package ID lowercased using the rules implemented by .NET's System.String.ToLowerInvariant() method.

Elsewhere on the page when there are sample URLs, you can also see that the package id is lowercase.

Additionally, at the top of the page it has a [small table about versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/api/registration-base-url-resource#versioning). As the docs say, using either the v3.0.0 or v3.4.0 registration base will not return you packages that use a SemVer2 version string. Therefore, if you want to avoid missing package versions, you should get `RegistrationsBaseUrl/3.6.0` and the lower case package id:

https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/stylecop.analyzers/index.json