# How to get nuget package metadata via the API?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I am fairly new to the nuget side. So I might be missing something. I have a list of nuget packages in several of the solutions of my team. And I would like to get their metadata(only the latest version of each would suffice) for each one of them. I plan to run an API on each name of the package which will retrieve the data. 
This is the JS API which I am trying to run, but I believe something is missing.

`https://api.nuget.org/v3/catalog0/${packageName}.json`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55386326/6630504
The answer here says that I need some {@id}. How do I get that? Is it required? What would be the end URL?

Answer (score 1):

what I do is I take the name of the Nuget Package and set it in my URL

so [https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/{name}/index.json](https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/%7Bname%7D/index.json)

would become https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/Walter.Web.Firewall.Core.3.x/index.json

then it generates a JSON response for you.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get that? Is it required? What would be the end URL?

It seems that the {@id} you need is `https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer`.

See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/api/package-base-address-resource#download-package-manifest-nuspec), for newtonsoft.json with version 6.0.4.

GET {@id}/{LOWER_ID}/{LOWER_VERSION}/{LOWER_ID}.nuspec

=>

GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/newtonsoft.json/6.0.4/newtonsoft.json.nuspec

{LOWER_ID}=>newtonsoft.json, {LOWER_VERSION}=>6.0.4, so I think the `{@id}` you need refers to `https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer` if the packages have been published to nuget.org.

Hope it helps.